# Is it a good design to index XML using elasticsearch?

Tags: xml, indexing, elasticsearch

I am working on a log management application that collects logs from multiple locations and indexes them into an elasticsearch cluster.

Every single line of logging contains an XML of variable length which may at times be as long as 30KB.

The question is : Is it a good idea to index the entire XML as a field in Elasticsearch OR is it better to just save it in something like cassandra / hbase and only extract the fields that i want to search with.

I know most will probably suggest the latter but extracting fields is going to be a complex development task .Just wondering if the whole XML can be indexed and then searched by treating attribs / elements as substrings.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Logstash](http://logstash.net/) to index the whole XML document using an [XML](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/xml) filter which will make it easier to search for specific elements in the XML document.